# Let ${Y_t}$ be a stationary process with mean zero and let $a$ and $b$ be constants. Prove $X_t$ is a stationary

Tags: time-series, stationary-processes

Let ${Y_t}$ be a stationary process with mean zero and let $a$ and $b$ be constants. Show that $X_t = Y_t - Y_{t-1} - Y_{t-12} + Y_{t-13}$ is stationary.

I encountered this issue when working on a problem with the following solution:
[image]

Is there any theorem I can quickly reference for this? Checking the mean, variance, and covariance of $X_t$ is somewhat time-consuming (because I need to work quickly during the exam).

I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi: You don't need to calculate those things because

1. the $s_t$ have period 12 so the 12 lag difference on the second and third terms, namely $s_{t}-s_{t-12}$ and $s_{t-1} - s_{t-13}$, make them stationary. ( not sure how you got rid of them on the next line ? ).
2. The question says that $Y_t$ is stationary.

So, all three terms that are left are stationary ( of course $b \times 0 = 0$ ) and the sum of the three terms is stationary.

Comment: Thank you for your help. As I understand, $s_t$ have period 12 so $s_t = s_{t-12}$ and $s_{t-1} = s_{t-13}$. I wonder if $X_t, Y_t$ is stationary, could I concluse $aX_{t} + bY_{t}$ is stationary for all $a, b \in R$?

Comment: I  don't know if the necessarily equal each other because of the lags  but when you subtract them you definitely get a stationary series. You may be correct there. I have to look back in my Box-Jenkins text and check. Either way, the result is either zero or its stationary.

Comment: If $X_t$  and $Y_{t}$ are stationary, then $Z_t = aX_t + bY_t$ is stationary for all $|a| < 1$ and $|b| < 1$.

Comment: @dienhosp3 No, you cannot conclude that. Take $X_t$ an IID sequence of $N(0,1)$ random variables and $Y_t= (-1)^t X_t$. You can check both $X_t$ and $Y_t$ are stationary, but $X_t + Y_t$ is not. The constraint suggested above also doesn't work, since $\frac{1}{2} (X_t + Y_t)$ is also not stationary. You need joint stationarity to conclude that for linear combinations.

Comment: @Jose Avilez: Can you provide an example where the constraint suggested does not work. Thanks.

Comment: @markleeds I did; read my previous comment.

Comment: Hi Jose: If you are referring to your $(-1)^t X_t$ example,  I should have included the condition that the coefficients $a$ and $b$ should not be functions of $t$ and should be independent.  I also should A) not have restricted the coefficients to have their absolute values less than 1.0 but B) restricted them to be independent. .dienhosp3: If we add the condition that the coefficients are not functions of $t$ and add the independence condition, then you are correct that the linear combination is stationary for all $a$ and $b$.

Comment: And my apologies for the statement about coefficients needing their absolute values to be less than 1.0. It must have been late in the night when I answered. Here is an interesting thread on stationarity and how I realized that I need to add the independence condition. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/337636/is-stationarity-preserved-under-a-linear-combination

Comment: And thanks to Jose for making me realize that one needs the "coefficients not be a function of $t$" condition.

Comment: @markleeds the coefficients in my example are both $1/2$. Indeed, the sum of two independent stationary processes is again stationary, although that's a bit restrictive; you can get away with joint stationarity instead, which works for the question above.

Comment: @Jose Avilez: Yes. The joint stationarity is all one needs ( along with the coefficients not being functions of $t$ )  but, given the nature of the OP's question,  I chose independence in order not to deal with the concept of  joint stationarity.  That concept is  more tricky and I figured it was best to avoid it in this case.

Comment: @dienhosp3: Just to summarize-clarify: Your statement about the linear combination being stationary for  $a$ and $b \in R$ is correct but one needs the additional conditions of A) joint stationarity ( or independence but joint stationarity is less restrictive. I'd rather not get into the difference between them ) and that the coefficients are NOT functions of $t$. I hope that everything is clear now and my apologies for any confusion.